# Swift4 Playgrounds Caesar Cipher error

Tags: swift, algorithm, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to make a caesar cipher in Swift Playgrounds but whenever the letter is for example "W" and I'm trying to shift it by 4, instead of getting "A" I just get an error. If the ascii code + shift doesn't exceed the ascii code for Z, it works just fine, otherwise I get

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Here is my code:

```
func cipher(messageToCipher: String, shift: UInt32) {
    var ciphredMessage = ""

    for char in messageToCipher.unicodeScalars {
        var unicode : UInt32 = char.value

        if char.value > 64 && char.value < 123 {
            var modifiedShift = shift
            if char.value >= 65 && char.value <= 90 {
                while char.value + modifiedShift > 90 {
                 //return to A
                    modifiedShift -= 26
                }
            } else if char.value >= 97 && char.value <= 122 {
                while char.value + modifiedShift > 122 {
                  //return to a
                    modifiedShift -= 26
                }
            }

            unicode = char.value + modifiedShift
        }

        ciphredMessage += String(UnicodeScalar(unicode)!)
    }

    print(ciphredMessage)
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I get error when the ascii code for the letter + shift exceeds the "z"'s ascii code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shift` is `UInt32`. So, with `var modifiedShift = shift`, `modifiedShift` is inferred to be `UInt32`, too. So when you set `modifiedShift` to 4, and then try to subtract 26 from it, that's not an acceptable `UInt32` value.

Bottom line, use signed integers.

Comment: @AndreiVataselu It is just not allowed for a `UInt32` value to be lower than 0. Otherwise you can subtract from it as long this condition is fulfilled

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment after I checked the range of UInt32 on the internet and realized I'm stupid. Thanks a lot man, didn't think a second about UInt32 ranges

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value of `modifiedShift` can be negative which is NOT allowed for a value of type `UInt32` so I would suggest to use only `Int` whenever you can:

```
// use `Int` for `shift`
func cipher(messageToCipher: String, shift: Int) {
    var ciphredMessage = ""

    for char in messageToCipher.unicodeScalars {
        // convert to `Int`
        var unicode = Int(char.value)

        if unicode > 64 && unicode < 123 {
            var modifiedShift = shift
            if unicode >= 65 && unicode <= 90 {
                while unicode + modifiedShift > 90 {
                    //return to A
                    modifiedShift -= 26
                }
            } else if unicode >= 97 && unicode <= 122 {
                while unicode + modifiedShift > 122 {
                    //return to a
                    modifiedShift -= 26
                }
            }

            unicode += modifiedShift
        }

        ciphredMessage += String(UnicodeScalar(unicode)!)
    }

    print(ciphredMessage)
}
```

Note: you can also use `if case` for range matching. The following lines are semantically equivalent:

```
if unicode > 64 && unicode < 123 { ... }
if case 65..<123 = unicode { ... }
if (65..<123).contains(unicode) { ... }
```